# Dealing with circular dependency in std::variant

Tags: c++, c++17, circular-dependency, variant

I'm trying to deal with circular dependency in following scenario:

I've got a std::variant, say:

```cpp
//types.h
using Types = std::variant<int, double, std::string, SomeClass>;
```

SomeClass is a pretty simple thing holding few pointers, with some template logic:

```cpp
#someclass.h
class SomeClass {
    // few simple members (pointers and an integer)
    
    void use(Types arg); // note usage of Types here

    template<typename T, typename Ts...> // implicitly assuming T == Ts... == Types
    void use(T arg, Ts... tail) {
        use(arg);
        use(tail...);
    }

    SomeClass(const SomeClass&) = default; // works fine
};
```

Usually I would forward-declare SomeClass before "using Types...", but it can't be done when it comes to std::variant. I also didn't really found a way to forward-declare the "using" directive.

One way I found was forward-declaring SomeClass and using a pointer to it in Types, but I don't like this idea (SomeClass is a really light object with short lifespan, I'd want to keep it out of heap).

Is there any other way (beside pointers) in C++ to solve this one? I'm running out of ideas.

Thanks :)

EDIT:

The issue actually appears only if I'm trying to use Types before really defining SomeClass, see https://godbolt.org/z/4jzhEd

Comment: What issue do you face exactly when you use a forward declared `SomeClass` in `std::variant`?

Comment: [Unable to reproduce with gcc](https://godbolt.org/z/MGEbe6). Compiles just fine (after fixing obvious typos and missing includes). I don't see a problem with this kind of forward declaration. Whatever your problem is, it must be something else. If you're using another compiler, perhaps a compiler bug.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/vPj4eE

Comment: I've managed to reproduce it https://godbolt.org/z/4jzhEd

Comment: Has nothing to do with circular dependencies or variants. Move the definition of `SomeStruct` ***after*** `SomeClass`. You simply cannot declare a class member whose type has not been defined. `class B; class A { B b; };  class B {};` -- this won't work either, for the same reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [live example you provided](https://godbolt.org/z/4jzhEd), all you need to solve the issue is define `SomeStruct` after `SomeClass`.

This way your `Types` variant will no longer have any incomplete types when `SomeStruct` is defined. In other words, here is the order:

```cpp
class SomeClass;

using Types = std::variant<..., SomeClass>;

class SomeClass {
   // ... // Types used here, but doesn't need to have all complete types
};

struct SomeStruct {
    Types value;
    // ...
};
```

[See here for a live example.](https://godbolt.org/z/xvcYvr)